# UITextField Placeholder Color

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Im fully aware that there are multiple answers already on this. I have added run time attributes. I have also added a UITextField extension. The placeholder color still refuses to change on simulator and device. I am not setting the placeholder through storyboard. Placeholder text is being set by retrieving data from database. Why won't my placeholder color change?

[image]

```
extension UITextField{
@IBInspectable var placeHolderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return self.placeHolderColor
    }
    set {
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:self.placeholder != nil ? self.placeholder! : "", attributes:[kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey: newValue!])
    }
}
  }
            func loadUserInfo(){
        if let username = user.name{
            self.nameLabel.text = username
            self.nameTextField.placeholder = username
           print(username)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems.

You call `self.nameTextField.placeholder = username`. This wipes out any attributed placeholder you may have in place and it goes back to the default color. You would need to set `placeHolderColor` after setting `placeholder` in order to see the color.

The `get` for your `placeHolderColor` computed property is going to cause infinite recursion since it calls `self.placeHolderColor` which calls the getter which calls `self.placeHolderColor` which calls the getter...

Comment: so I will have to set each text field in code after setting placeholder, rather than doing it through extension or interface builder?

Comment: Or you add some other custom property (or function) to your `UITextField` extension that lets you set the placeholder text while keeping whatever color has been setup already. Then you change `self.nameTextField.placeholder = username` to `self.nameTextField.myPlaceholder = username`.

Answer (score 0):

In loadUserInfo after getting users name I added `self.nameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:user.name, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green])`

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer to your question or additional details for the question?

Comment: Note that this makes your `placeHolderColor` property pointless.

Comment: yes i removed the extensions and run time attributes since it was pointless